# Querying MassTransit State Machine information

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, masstransit, state-machine, saga

Is it OK to use the DbContext used by MassTransit to store the StateMachines as a regular DbContext?

In my application we want to implement the following scenario (removed validation and err handling):

- A queue request comes in through an asp.net mvc api
- The request gets published by MassTransit. The correlation id is returned as response
- The request gets split in N smaller requests
- They smaller requests get handled in parallell
- If all the smaller requests are finished the main request is handled

The progress and status of the queue request should be queryable through the api.

If I read [the docs](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/saga/state-machine) correctly this is what StateMachine and Saga are used for.
The saga is working and tested, but now I want to implement the part where I can query the state information.

Should I use the EFCore DbContext that is used as persistance for MassTransit as a regular DbContext?
Is there an existing way to better communicate this data store is not for writing outside masstransit?
Is there a better way to interrogate a StateMachine or Saga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DbContext` is just that, there isn't anything special about it. So, you can certainly use it to query status. There are also other options to query status from a saga state machine using request/response. Various examples cover these details.

From your description, I'd suggest looking at [Sample-Batch](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Batch) which seems to do something similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: That is a really nice sample. Also answers my "how to know when done" question. Marked :)